# Joomla MVC Module delete model

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I'm a newbie on Joomla developing and I'm trying to fix an old administration module made by 'someone before me'. Module's been developed using MVC Components, it has several CRUDs and I'm stucked at deleting an item. The template view adds the toolbar icon like this:

```
JToolbarHelper::deleteList('', 'paises.delete', JTOOLBAR_DELETE);
```

It also has at the list controller (DistribuidoresControllerPaises), the getModel function:

```
public function getModel($name = 'Pais', $prefix = 'DistribuidoresModel', $config = array('ignore_request' => true))
{
    $model = parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);

    return $model;
}
```

The model class:

```
class DistribuidoresModelPais  extends JModelAdmin
```

When selecting an item on the list, and clicking the trash button an empty page opens with this ending:

> administrator/index.php?option=com_distribuidores&view=pais

If I come back to grid, the item still remains.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this by enabling debugging from Joomla configuration or you can try to to check with exit with in "delete" function of "paises" controller and can check you get item ids in post request or not.

Also you are using view "pais" also using model "pais" then why you are using "paises" controller for delete function, you should use "pais" controller to delete.

Also provide delete function which you are using to delete items, it may contain some issue.